# Mysql Query Result with N/A

Tags: mysql

Currenty I have records like below :

- name|score|

  tony|23|

  john|32|

  eddy|25|

  mark|21|

  nick|26|

  alex|27|

  nick|23|

I want to request table with only name like : tony, john, eddy, mike, paul
using this query below ;

```
SELECT name,
name
FROM a_team
WHERE (name LIKE  'tony%' or name LIKE 'john%' or name LIKE 'eddy%' or name LIKE 'mike%' or name LIKE 'paul%')
```

the result is :

- name|score|

  tony|23|

  john|32|

  eddy|25|

Since name like: mike and paul have no record yet
how do I request table with above query with result displaying
mike and paul = "n/a" in field "score" as below ?

- name|score|

  tony|23|

  john|32|

  eddy|25|

  mike|n/a|

  paul|n/a|

Thanks for response

Comment: This make no sense. As per your where condition in query, you will get record only when data exist in db. Suppose there is no data in your table or no data for name, tony, john, eddy. You will get 0 rows. So you need to add custom code to show N/A for them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot transfer the names from the criteria to the output rowset. You must make your criteria a rowset and join existing data to it:

```
SELECT criteria.name, COALESCE(a_team.score, 'N/A') score
FROM (
    SELECT 'tony' AS name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'john' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'eddy' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'mike' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'paul'
    ) criteria
LEFT JOIN a_team ON a_team.name LIKE CONCAT(criteria.name, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You can set the default values for the column, so when there is no value in the field it will return the default value from the database, for example for scores if your table name is `scores` you can run the query;

```
ALTER TABLE a_team MODIFY COLUMN scores VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT "N/A";
```

**NOTE:** N/A cannot be set for an integer field so you have to use varchar()

2- You can use `IFNULL` to replace the null values from the column:

```
SELECT name, IFNULL(score, 'N/A') AS score
FROM a_team
WHERE (name LIKE  'tony%' or name LIKE 'john%' or name LIKE 'eddy%' or name LIKE 'mike%' or name LIKE 'paul%')
```

Comment: Are you serious. Sure you understand the query. If you use condition as WHERE (name like 'zzz%'. The query return 0 rows. When there is no data how you can show N/A for this without custom code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Yogendra as far as I know we can set default value while creating the column so when there is no value in the field it will show default value